# i cannot find my project build.gradle file to add dependency

Tags: android

I cannot find my build.gradle project file to add dependency only my android studio contains 1 module build.gradle but cannot find the other one to add dependency.

[image]
i need to add the google vision dependency in my project but i am not getting where to write the dependency code
like

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'`

can please anyone help me out regarding this problem

Comment: try in java folder

Comment: add screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: add screenshot after complete gradle build

Comment: try to create it

Comment: You do not have any modules in your project...check setting.gradle

Comment: You have the build.gradle that you need to add the dependency to but you need the project build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project and then copy it from there